# ArangoDB goes silent after slurm sbatch submission

Tags: arangodb, slurm

I am trying to run ArangoDB in cluster-mode on a Cray-supercomputer.
It runs on a login node.
I followed these instructions:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/single-instance/

To make proper use of the Cray-cluster I however need to submit it as a batch-job (Slurm / sbatch).
I am having issues getting it running because "arangod" goes silent, that is its command-line output does not end up in the slurm-log-file.

I have tried to change the log-settings using this link:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/arangodb-server/options/#--loglevel
If I put the logging to "info" then I get nothing. If I use "trace" like this:

```
build/bin/arangod --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:5003 --agency.my-address tcp://148.187.32.9:5001 --server.authentication false --agency.activate true --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --database.directory db_dir/agency_2 --log.level startup=trace --log.level agency=trace --log.level queries=trace --log.level replication=trace --log.level threads=trace
```

I get something, but it does not print any line I'm interested in, namely if it created the database-directory, if it ends up in gossip-mode and so on. I don't get a line of the expected output I would get in the console if I just ran it from the terminal.

As I said: on the login-node it all works. I suspect the problem might be in the interaction of Slurm and arangod.

Can you help me?

*** EDIT ***

I ran a small experiment. First I ran this (expecting an error message):

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --job-name=slurm_test
#SBATCH --time=00:30:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-core=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --partition=debug
#SBATCH --constraint=mc

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

srun build/bin/arangod --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:5001
```

And got this (first line from arangodb, what we expect):
slurm-....out:

```
no database path has been supplied, giving up, please use the '--database.directory' option
srun: error: nid00008: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
srun: Terminating job step 8106415.0
 
Batch Job Summary Report for Job "slurm_test" (8106415) on daint
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Submit            Eligible               Start                 End    Elapsed  Timelimit 
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- 
2018-06-20T22:41:54 2018-06-20T22:41:54             Unknown             Unknown   00:00:00   00:30:00 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Username    Account     Partition   NNodes   Energy
----------  ----------  ----------  ------  --------------
peterem     g34         debug            1          joules
 
This job did not utilize any GPUs
 
----------------------------------------------------------
Scratch File System        Files       Quota
--------------------  ----------  ----------
/scratch/snx3000           85020     1000000
```

Then I ran this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --job-name=slurm_test
#SBATCH --time=00:30:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-core=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --partition=debug
#SBATCH --constraint=mc

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

srun build/bin/arangod --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:5001 --agency.my-address tcp://127.0.0.1:5001 --server.authentication false --agency.activate true --agency.size 1 --agency.supervision true --database.directory agency1
```

This created the "agency1" directory but did not complete (ran for over 3min). So after a few minutes I "scancel" the job. This is the only output (slurm-....out:):

```
srun: got SIGCONT
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 8106340.0 ON nid00008 CANCELLED AT 2018-06-20T22:38:03 ***
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 8106340 ON nid00008 CANCELLED AT 2018-06-20T22:38:03 ***
srun: forcing job termination
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
 
Batch Job Summary Report for Job "slurm_test" (8106340) on daint
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Submit            Eligible               Start                 End    Elapsed  Timelimit 
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- 
2018-06-20T22:32:15 2018-06-20T22:32:15             Unknown             Unknown   00:00:00   00:30:00 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Username    Account     Partition   NNodes   Energy
----------  ----------  ----------  ------  --------------
peterem     g34         debug            1          joules
 
This job did not utilize any GPUs
 
----------------------------------------------------------
Scratch File System        Files       Quota
--------------------  ----------  ----------
/scratch/snx3000           85020     1000000
```

So: I know it is running in both cases (gives output or crates folder). But I have no idea why it gives no output in the second case.

I hope this clarifies my issue.

Thanks, Emanuel

Answer (score 0):

Would you please print your entire `slurm` job command / job file? `arangod` logs to `stdout`. When `stdout` is redirected to an output file, as cluster batch systems do per default, you should monitor that file. As far as I remember slurm per default writes to `slurm-$jobid.out`

Comment: Thanks for asking for details. Do you have an idea what might be going on?

Comment: did you look for `slurm-$jobid.out` that i mentioned above. the output is piped to those files. this is not an arangodb behaviour. this is how slurm does things.

Comment: Yes, what I call the output are these files you mention.
slurm-....out
They contain first the stdout and then the "batch job summary".